# How can I rotate a barcode in Java/iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, barcode

As far as I know, barcode as such can't be rotated (iReport doesn't have that property and neither does the Barbecue Barcode in a Java class). I've seen some examples, but they are incomplete and I don't understand how to use them, eg.:

```
public class BarbecueRenderer extends JRAbstractSvgRenderer
{

private boolean rotate;
private Barcode barcode = null;

public BarbecueRenderer(Barcode barcode) 
{
    this(barcode, false);
}

public BarbecueRenderer(Barcode barcode, boolean rotate) 
{
    this.barcode = barcode;
    this.rotate = rotate;
}

// What should I use as the grx and rectangle objects?
public void render(Graphics2D grx, Rectangle2D rectangle) 
{
    if (barcode != null) 
    {
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) grx.create();
        graphics.translate(rectangle.getX(), rectangle.getY());
        if (rotate)
        {
            graphics.translate(barcode.getBounds().getHeight(), 0);
            graphics.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
        }
        barcode.draw(graphics, 0, 0);
    }
}
}
```

What I need is something like this:

```
 Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode39("128", false);
 // rotate the barcode
 File f = new File ("c:\\barcode.jpg");
 BarcodeImageHandler.saveJPEG(barcode, f);
```

Comment: http://www.barcodelib.com/java_barcode/main.html

Comment: Forgot to mention, need to do it free :)

Answer (score 2):

In jasper reports 4.0.2 you can simply edit the jrxml and add the rotation attribute to the jr:barbecue element.

```
<jr:barbecue xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" type="Code128" drawText="true" checksumRequired="true" rotation="Right">
```

Possible values are any valid [net.sf.jasperreports.engine.type.RotationEnum](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/RotationEnum.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I must use 2.0.2. In the end we dropped the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public BufferedImage rotate90DX(BufferedImage bi)
    {
        int width = bi.getWidth();
        int height = bi.getHeight();

        BufferedImage biFlip = new BufferedImage(height, width, bi.getType());

        for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
                biFlip.setRGB(height-1-j, width-1-i, bi.getRGB(i, j));

        return biFlip;
    }
```

As found at :

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2936